# How to fix broken hotkey with remapped keyboard?

Tags: shortcut

I've recently moved to a PC from a Mac, and I've had some trouble replicating my Blender hotkeys on Windows 10.

I've remapped my Left Windows key to "Alt" and I'd like to use it in the operations "Alt+G" and "Alt+R" ("Clear Position" and "Clear Rotation" using the 2.7x default keymapping). However, for some reason, Blender will not allow this. "Alt+S" works fine, as do other operations involving the key, but Alt+G and Alt+R will not work with my remapped key. The operations do work just fine with other keys bound to "alt," however.

How can I make these hotkeys function properly? I'm a bit at a loss.

(If it's relevant, I used "Power Toys" to remap my keys.)

Thanks!